# MySQL GROUP BY and remove null rows

Tags: mysql

how am i going to hit my goal? i made an initial query but i can't proceed on how to remove this null/blank rows. i am so grateful if anyone could extend a help.

this is my query:

[image: my query]

this is the result:
[image: first result]

but i need to remove all blank/null rows such as this to get my desired result:
[image: desired result]

Comment: That output doesn't look like MySQL. Just sayin'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use conditional aggregation.  Something like:

```
select . . .,
       max(case when tr.id = 445 then ap.abbreviation end) as `2011-01`,
       . . .
```

You can use `if()` instead of `case`.  I prefer the latter because it is ANSI standard.

AND you need to change the `group by`clause by removing `tr_id`.

Comment: sorry Gordon Linoff the result has no difference but only reordered

Comment: That's the former. Oh, I see

Comment: @tatskie . . . You also need to remove `tr.id` from the `group by` clause and `select` clause.